# What happens to variables declared in a block?

Tags: java, android, c++

I want to know what happens to a variable declared in block after exiting that block?

I mean ...

for example I'm using a while loop
then I declare an integer `i` in it

after the loop ends
does the program release the memory used by that integer? or the memory isn't free until we destroy the application? or only GC gets that part of memory free?

Comment: This actually depends on the language. So pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a local variable it is on the stack.

This stack is allocated when you enter a method, and freed when you return from a method.  This stack is created when you start the thread and freed when you end the thread.  The main thread you start with might not be freed until you exit the program.

In many ways C++ and Java are the same as they both are compiled to machine code and this machine works the same as there is a single CPU architecture.

Comment: you mean this : 

while(i < 10000) {int temp = 1; i++;}

gets more memory than :

int temp; while(i < 10000) {temp = 1, i++}

both running on main ?

(c++ and java ?)

Comment: @user2589881 there is no difference once the code is compiled.

Comment: `temp` should be eliminated as it is not used. However, even if it where not the stack allocation would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are stored in `Stack`. When they get out of scope they are poped out of the stack.